# Adding Multiple Values to Single Key in Python Dictionary Comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

I wanted to learn how to use dictionary comprehension and decided to use one for the previously solved task. I need to assign multiple values to the same key. I was wondering if there's a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do than with the code I've written so far.

```
graph = {(x1,y1): [(c,d) for a,b,c,d in data if a == x1 and b == y1] for x1 ,y1, x2, y2 in data}
```

For example I have this:

```
data = {(1,2,1,5),(1,2,7,2),(1,5,4,7),(4,7,7,5)}
```

The first two values should create a key and the remaining two should be added as a value of a key.
With the given example I would like to return:

```
{(1, 2): [(1, 5), (7, 2)], (1, 5): [(4, 7)], (4, 7): [(7, 5)]}
```

Is there an easier way to do it than iterate through the entire data just to find the matching values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this dict comprehension isn’t an efficient way here. It loops over the same input data repeatedly.

It's more Pythonic to just use a simple for loop, iterating the data only once:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = {(1,2,1,5),(1,2,7,2),(1,5,4,7),(4,7,7,5)}
output = defaultdict(list)

for a, b, c, d in data:
    output[a, b].append((c, d))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is the best answer but I would do something like that :

```
m_dict = {}
for val in data:
    key = (val[0],val[1])
    if key in m_dict:
        m_dict[key].append((val[2],val[3]))
    else:
        m_dict[key] = [(val[2],val[3])]
```

Or more concisely using `setdefault`:

```
m_dict = {}
for val in data:
    key = (val[0],val[1])
    obj = m_dict.setdefault(key,[])
    obj.append((val[2],val[3]))
```

Comment: This is what I had before :) It does its job much better than the two loops I've in the above example, thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: You can also shorten `(val[0],val[1])` to `(val[:2])` and `(val[2],val[3])` to `(val[2:])`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is neat but the time complexity is O(n^2), which can be reduced to O(n).

```
data = {(1,2,1,5),(1,2,7,2),(1,5,4,7),(4,7,7,5)}
result = dict()
for item in data:
    key = (item[0],item[1])
    value = result.setdefault(key,[])
    value.append((item[2],item[3]))
    result[key] = value
print result
```

In my opinion, using a for loop can make codes more comprehensive

Comment: instead doing all this you could use setdefault method of the dictionary

Comment: this can be even more simplified remove all the things in for loop and write  `result.setdefault((item[0],item[1]),[]).append((item[2],item[3]))`

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, I would use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). For your example:

```
dict(groupby(data, lambda t: (t[0], t[1])))
```

This will produce a dict with the keys equal to `(1, 2), (1, 5), and (4, 7)` and the values consisting of `(1, 2, 1, 5), (1, 2, 7, 2)...` which should be sufficient for most uses. You can also post-process the grouped list, if need be.

---

As noted in the comments below, `groupby` requires sorted data. As such, you will need to sort before grouping and will probably want to cast the iterator to a list:

```
first_two = lambda tup: (tup[0], tup[1])
groups = groupby(sorted(data, key=first_two), first_two)
target = {k: list(g) for k, g in groups}
```

Comment: groupby requires sorted data

Comment: the output return an iterator `{(1, 2): <itertools._grouper at 0x747b430>,
` not a list

Comment: Both of those are true. However, it solves the problem. I will amend my answer.